# Undefined reference to defined functions

Tags: reference, undefined, rpm

I am trying to build rpm from source.  I think configure did not find the bzip2 library correctly.  Now I am getting undefined references on a compiled library.  I added -L/usr/lib -lbz2 to the Makefile but I am still getting these errors :

> root:/usr/src/rpm/rpm-4.4.2.3/rpmio/.libs#   nm librpmio-4.4.so |
>   grep BZ2
>              U BZ2_bzclose
>              U BZ2_bzdopen
>              U BZ2_bzerror
>              U BZ2_bzflush
>              U BZ2_bzopen
>              U BZ2_bzread
>              U BZ2_bzwrite

I would like to correct the errors without having to configure again.

Comment: What problem are you actually having? That output looks normal to me. That library should link against libbz2 and resolve them at runtime. Is that not the case? What does `ldd librpmio-4.4.so | grep bz2` output?

Comment: I could not compile rpm because of these compilation errors.  The ldd function returns 'libbz2.so.1.0 => /lib/libbz2.so.1.0 (0xb7799000)'.  /usr/lib/libbz2.so is symlinked to /lib/libbz2.so.1.0.  Can it be resolved directly in the library at compile time ?

Comment: What errors were you getting exactly? When trying to compile what exactly? That library appears to be compiled correctly and should therefore work correctly when linked against.